# How to add icon and fanart to xbmc addon on menu

Tags: python, image, icons, xbmc

I can get them to show up within the addon, but I can't get them to show up on the addon select screen. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? (this is my first addon and I'm new at this so please forgive if it's a rookie mistake.)

```
 import sys
import xbmcgui
import xbmcplugin

addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])

xbmcplugin.setContent(addon_handle, 'audio')

url = 'http://chadmasta5.weebly.com/uploads/6/0/1/9/6019696/listen.pls'
li = xbmcgui.ListItem('Listen', iconImage='http://i60.tinypic.com/2hnozec.png')
li.setProperty('fanart_image', 'http://i59.tinypic.com/b669vt.jpg')
xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=addon_handle, url=url, listitem=li)

xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(addon_handle)
```

Comment: You have to select your addon in order for your addon's code to be executed. Given that, I'm not sure that getting ListItem to show up in the addon selection screen is possible.